# Unable to use async-await with AcceptTcpClientAsync method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, network-programming, async-await

I saw a lot of code snippets like here:

```
TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
Logger.Info("Client accepted");
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/wpf-async-await-tcpclient-tcplistener-sample

```
var tcpClient = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
HandleConnectionAsync(tcpClient);
```

https://bsmadhu.wordpress.com/2012/09/29/simplify-asynchronous-programming-with-c-5-asyncawait/

It seems like it works for the most of people. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me -- compiler gives me the following error:

> error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async
>   method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and
>   changing its return type to 'Task'

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you considered marking that method with the `async` modifier and changing its return type to `Task`? Just a thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Exactly as the error states, the *calling* method needs to be marked with the `async` modifier and have a return type of `Task` or `Task<T>`:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync()
{
    TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
    Logger.Info("Client accepted");
}
```